# Is my Power Supply Unit fried?

Tags: laptop, charger

So my laptop just started smoking where I plug my charger in. I run a netbook, the Acer Aspire One.

My charger won't charge it, because when I plug my charger into the netbook, the charging light that indicates the netbook is receiving power turns off.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot where the problem is and what should I do now? Is just my charger fried and should I replace it. Or could there also be a problem with my netbook and do I need to look for other problems?

Comment: I have one simple rule for electrical equipment of all kind: If it smoked, it's toast. You don't plug toast into a wall socket, do you? No seriously, your laptop or at least its psu is fried, get professional help (no pun intended).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot tell you how many charge ports I have soldered back together on various laptops.  Bobby's comment is for the most part true, if it smokes it is likely done for, but sometimes you can get lucky.  I would take your laptop apart and see if the charge port is broken off (very likely).  If it is solder it back on and see what happens.  Take it to someone to do it if you don't have good soldering skills.

**UPDATE:**

Check out [this link](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop/2008/10/28/fortify-damaged-power-jack-connection-in-laptop/) and look at the pictures.  The little cube piece that is broken off is the charge port, probably more accurately referred to as the power jack.  It is common for this piece to break loose.  If it is badly damaged (melted or deformed) you can likely find a suitable replacement on eBay.

Comment: Also please be aware that taking apart the laptop will void your warranty (**if any**).

Comment: Its not completely broken off. I can see where it burned. The gold wiring is burn at the bottom.

Comment: @Rob do you have the laptop apart (motherboard removed)? Gold is typically used for the contact points of connectors, not in places where solder is required. See my updated answer for some pics that might help clear things up.

Comment: I just received a Aspire One netbook after similar thing. Your advise isn't applicable here. In AAO (Acer Aspire One) the socket isn't soldered to MB (Mother/Main Board) but it's separate piece, cabled to another small SMD socket. When I taken the netbook apart found one piece that came off: appears to be big resistor (LP3) on the back/bottom of board and it's not only fired, but also it's de-soldered itself from board! Can't tell much more yet whether why and what caused it, but looks a bit serious with burned MB and chassis in this place. No other elements are burned by visual inspection.

Answer (score 2):

## UNPLUG YOUR LAPTOP IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: Thank you, but I already have.

Comment: CARE TO EXPLAIN WHY @HELLO71?!?

Comment: SMOKING ELECRIC EQUIPMENT IS USUALLY BAD AND MAY LEAD TO CATASTROPHIC FIRES AND/OR EXPLOSIONS @IVO‽‽‽

Comment: Ahhhhhh, my brain is melting, too many caps!