# Toshiba laptop charger not working properly?

Tags: hardware-failure, charger

I have a Toshiba laptop and basically, for the laptop to charge I have to apply a lot of pressure to the charger, so it shifts to the right, and it charges. My laptop's battery holds only 10 minutes max, so I would have to hold it all the time like that. Is there anything I could do myself?

I can't send it to a repairing center or buy a new charger. The laptop is **Toshiba L305-S5921**. So, again, I have to shift and apply pressure to the tip of the charger for it to charge. Tape won't hold it as it needs a lot of pressure.

I am okay to open the laptop as long as I know that it's for sure fixable.

Comment: pressure is never good. you need to check the amps on the charger and check if it is indeed working properly as it might damage your computer. only then, i would open the case to check the connector for problems. recap: consider by all means to have it seen by a professional with proper tools to address your problem.

Comment: I have been using this charger for years. This is the default charger that comes with the laptop. It stopped working a week ago. I have to shift it to the side a little bit so it starts charging. Now, however, it doesn't want to charge at all without pressure, like a LOT of pressure. I can't take it to the store because I have no money, I am 16.

Comment: I assume you can't talk it over with your parents?

Comment: We hate each other, there is absolutely no way they will pay for me.

Comment: ok, that is a department I won't meddle into. Still, you need to have it checked properly.

Comment: Do you know if I could open it up? I think it's a problem with the hole in the charger? Maybe I need to move it a bit?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/231034/is-my-power-supply-unit-fried/231083#231083

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/236604/how-to-test-ac-adapter?rq=1

Comment: http://www.google.ca/search?q=Toshiba+L305-S5921+disassembly

Comment: The charger works. Call me stupid but I put my tongue in it and it did shock me.

Comment: @techie007 quick and accurate as always :)

Comment: If the charger is good, bust out the soldering iron and get to fixin'!  Good luck! PS: if you do open it, keep track of your screws, and where they came from. :)

Comment: Problem was with the charger, I will find a new one in Radio Shack.

Comment: @techie007 you know you just told a kid who test current with his tounge to use a soldering iron... How is he going to test it?

Comment: I hope he is short on pets nearby.

Comment: @50-3 You telling me you've never tested a 9-volt battery with your tongue? :)  Besides, you only have to touch a hot soldering iron once to learn that lesson.

Comment: I actually used to solder my Armani glasses, but I accidentally touched the lense. I just called RadioShack, and it's 9.98 + taxes. I have exactly 10, so I am in luck. :D

Comment: @techie007 my dad is a electrical engineer I got a multimeter for my 12th birthday

Comment: Yeah but my dad is in a different continent, my stepdad likes to get in my face and my mom doesn't talk to me at all. I have a very happy family.

Comment: @50-3 Well one day when your short a multimeter and you need to know if a 9-volt has any juice, you're ready.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem , just replace the jack where you connect the charger, there is nothing wrong with the charger and i replaced 4 chargers but problem wasnt solved, just go to laptop shop and replace the jack where you connect the charger--

Comment: I know this is a little late, but this was an issue with the jack.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue to this with my laptop charger twice over the years and I found that replacing the charger cord fixed the issue. Upon inspection of the tip of the cord the plastic shroud was very weak and in my case a tiny bit was missing which was exposing the wire. Only when applying pressure in a very specific spot could I get the laptop to charge. Take a look at your charger and see if there is any abnormalities with the shroud or the tip of the cord.

Comment: My first thought as well, hard to see where/how pressure is being applied on the Internet though. :(  If he gets a zap in the tongue, that's actually a good sign that it's not the cord.  Not fool-proof though. ;)

Comment: YES another charger (HP) fit my hole and it charged and worked flawlessly. It's the charger's fault. THANKS ALL OF YOU!

Comment: I'd be wary of using another charger from another computer. Make sure it has the same voltage before really plugging that thing in.

Comment: @user0000001 http://superuser.com/questions/448288/fix-a-laptop-charger

Comment: @user0000001 http://superuser.com/questions/32372/can-i-safely-charge-my-laptop-with-a-non-standard-third-party-charger